# Enabling PowerShell Remoting with psexec as script

Tags: powershell, psexec

If I run:

```
C:\psexec.exe \\$compname -s powershell Enable-PSRemoting -Force
```

as a command it works fine, but as soon as I put it into a foreach loop I get an error message saying the handle is invalid. Any way to fix this?

Here's my loop:

```
$computerlist = Get-Content C:\computernames\WorkstationList.txt

foreach ($compname in $computerlist){

C:\psexec.exe \\$compname -s powershell Enable-PSRemoting -Force 

}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some samples of the hostnames (obfuscated, but similarly listed - including obscure characters if present, etc.) that are within WorkstationList?

My guess is that the data present in there isn't being handled appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

psexec -@WorkstationList.txt -s powershell Enable-PSRemoting -Force